# chrome.declarativeNetRequest: How to allow blocked URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I want to make a Chrome extension that initially blocks the access to a specific website (e.g. example.com), and then, based on some conditions, it allows the user to access it.

As a starting point, I have used the source code from [Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api-samples/declarativeNetRequest/url-blocker) that blocks the access to the above mentioned domain name. However, I have read the official documentation from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/), but I have not found any specifications concerning how to modify the RuleActionType of a static rule. There is mentioned just how to enable/disable rules, not how to modify there parameters.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You add a new rule for this url with a bigger `priority` and type: allow.

Comment: Hi, @wOxxOm! Based on some additional conditions in the onRuleMatchedDebug method, I would like to further block, or allow the request to the URL. I would like something like "return {cancel: true};" as I would do in the onBeforeRequest method in manifest v2. But, I do not know how to do the same for onRuleMatchedDebug in chrome.declarativeNetRequest.

Comment: There's no such thing. It's rule-based so you need to add a rule for each condition.